# How to get data from multiple table

Tags: mysql

i have 3 table i m merge two table by join  but cant Merge more then 3 table

multiple time

```
$query="select * from emp_table INNER JOIN emp_salary on emp_table.emp_id=emp_salary.emp_id";
```

how to get get three table data in singe table

Comment: Add another join?  I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Hi. I have 3 table Like emp_table,emp_salary,emp_address ,i can get data from database from 2 table emp_table and emp_salary but unable to get data from address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general pattern you might use here would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp_table emp
INNER JOIN emp_salary sal
    ON emp.emp_id = sal.emp_id
INNER JOIN emp_address addr
    ON emp.emp_id = addr.emp_id;
```

But note that in practice `SELECT *` should be avoided (I only used it because I don't know in which columns, from which tables, you are interested).  Your actual PHP script should only select the columns you really need.

Comment: Right it's Work .$query="select * from emp_table INNER JOIN emp_salary on emp_table.emp_id=emp_salary.emp_id INNER JOIN emp_address on emp_table.emp_id=emp_address.emp_id";